# How to hide keyboard without animation in swift 2?

Tags: swift, swift2, uikeyboard

I have a segmented control that switches between 3 views, one of which is a chat. I have an @IBAction set up to that segmented control for when the index (tab selected) changes. Since I want the keyboard to go down, the first thing I do is call my dismissKeyboard function:

```
func dismissKeyboard() {
    view.endEditing(true)
}
```

The problem is this method has a sliding down animation, I would want it to just disappear. Looking for a Swift 2 solution

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```
UIView.performWithoutAnimation {
    self.view.endEditing(true)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's not possible in Swift 2 or 3 to dismiss a keyboard without the slide down animation.

`resignFirstResponder` doesn't take any arguments.